# how to make blur image on android? React-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I need to do a blur effect on Image component on Android with react native,
this is possible or how can i do it?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require('../../Images/bgImg.png')}
        style={styles.imagen}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into this? https://github.com/rexlow/react-native-blur

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make the blur effect with react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131278/how-to-make-the-blur-effect-with-react-native)

Comment: yeah but I wanted to look for other options

Comment: this is for IOS

Comment: you can use opacity on view to make image little invisible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can now set *blurRadius* property on your Image.

```
<Image
  style={styles.imagen}
  source={require('../../Images/bgImg.png')} 
  blurRadius={1}
/>
```

Or you can use a community library such as https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-blur which works on both iOS and Android

Answer (score 0):

Use Attribute `blurRadius` increase the number to get more blurred image .

```
<Image 
    source={require('../../Images/bgImg.png')}
    style={styles.imagen}
    blurRadius={1}
    />
```