# React Native - How to do Blur View like iOS or instagram?

Tags: react-native, view, blur, blurry, uiblureffect

**Background Transparency with BLUR**

Is it possible to blur view without using background Image? I want to show the **parent content** on top of the **background blur view** in **modal**.

Similar kind of this:

[image: blur view]

**Tried with [react-native-blur](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-blur) :**

Its actually blurring the background image. I want to blur and show the content which is behind the modal.

**Tried along with [react-native-overlay](https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-overlay) :** But no change.

Comment: If you're using Expo, https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/blur-view would work, wouldn't it?

Comment: But am not using Expo.

Comment: Well, too bad then 

Comment: Please add some code to your question to get a better and relative answer. `react-native-blur` should work bu you might be using it wrong

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/voronianski/react-native-effects-view ?

Answer (score 15):

well if you are

> using expo

then you should go and check out this link **[here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/blur-view)**

**else** if you are like me

> who loves to use '**react-native init**' and want some blurry effect based views then i have this for you!

https://github.com/voronianski/react-native-effects-view

an awesome library

it would be very simple to use it like

"if the dialogbox is open then render The blur view else render simple",

here is a simple example for basic how to use!

```
...imports
var EffectsView = require('react-native-effects-view');

var App = React.createClass({
renderVibrant() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Do you feel blurry??</Text>
        </View>
    );
},

render() {
    return (
        <EffectsView 
            style={styles.view} 
            blurStyle="dark" 
            vibrantContent={this.renderVibrant()}
        >
            <Image style={styles.bg} source={require('image!bg')} />
        </EffectsView>
    );
}
});
```

Comment: Expo BlurView link is dead here is an updated one https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/blur-view